# Godot: having problems with the raycasting

Tags: godot

I am making a sort of map where points are randomly generated. Each point will then detect all the points nearest to it and draw a line there. I have tried making an Area2D around the points which would detect the other points and draw the lines.

This has worked, but only one line is being drawn to one point, even when there are other points intersecting the area. I did not know how to fix this until I thought of the idea to use raycasting instead of an area2d. It would be able to detect all of the points and just generally be more efficient.

However, this is my first time using raycasting, as I am fairly new to coding and game making. I have set up the rays and some code, but it is still not working.

Code:

```
var point_a = self.get_global_position()
var point_b = 0

var draw_line = false

func _process(delta):
    var ray_list = [$RayCast2D]
    
    for rays in ray_list:
        if rays.is_colliding() and rays.get_collider().get_parent() == "Location":
            point_b = rays.get_collider().get_parent().get_global_position()
            
            draw_line = true
            
            update()
    
func _draw():
    if draw_line:
        draw_line(point_a, to_local(point_b), Color(1, 1, 1, 1), 2)
        
        draw_line = false
```

Any help with this problem would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What I can tell is that both

```
var point_a = self.get_global_position()
```

And

```
point_b = rays.get_collider().get_parent().get_global_position()
```

Are in global coordinates.

However, you only transform to local `point_b`:

```
draw_line(point_a, to_local(point_b), Color(1, 1, 1, 1), 2)
```

Transform both:

```
draw_line(to_local(point_a), to_local(point_b), Color(1, 1, 1, 1), 2)
```

Although the position of the `self` in its own local coordinantes (i.e. relative to itself) is always the zero vector:

```
draw_line(Vector2.ZERO, to_local(point_b), Color(1, 1, 1, 1), 2)
```

---

Besides that… Read this:

```
point_b = rays.get_collider().get_parent().get_global_position()
```

It is the global position of the parent of the collider. Is that what you want?

If you want the position of the collider, it would be:

```
point_b = rays.get_collider().get_global_position()
```

And if you want the position where the ray hit, it would be:

```
point_b = rays.get_collision_point()
```

*And yes, that is global coordinates too.*

---

**Addendum**: The result of `get_parent` here:

```
if rays.is_colliding() and rays.get_collider().get_parent() == "Location":
```

Should be a `Node`, right? And a `Node` is not a `String`. So it will never be equal to `"Location"`.

Presumably you meant to check the `name`:

```
rays.get_collider().get_parent().name == "Location"
```

An alternative approach would be checking groups. For example:

```
rays.get_collider().get_parent().is_in_group("Location")
```

And if you use groups for the `Node`s directly, then you don't have to consider their parent:

```
rays.get_collider().is_in_group("Location")
```

Yoo can set the groups from the editor in the Node panel (it is next to the inspector by default) on the Groups tab.

Comment: I have done some of those changes, however the problem still persists. At this point, the lines are not even being drawn.

Comment: @AbsolutePickle42 Well, next thing that comes to mind is to remove the `draw_line` *variable*. You are already calling `update` which should trigger the re-draw.

Comment: That does not work either. I did change the draw function to a custom function with the draw_line in it, which would be called whenever a ray collides, but still it does not work. I had a thought that if the lines are not being drawn in any way then that might relate to the rays not detecting any collision. I have set them to detect area2D's, but that might not be working

Comment: @AbsolutePickle42 If you want to test if the `RayCast2D` is detecting something, you use a `breakpoint` or a `print`. Using `_draw` for custom drawing is correct, if you want to move away from it, perhaps try having a child `Line2D` instead. Edit: are you enabling Visible Collision Shapes in Debug? If not, that might help.

Comment: I am enabling Visible Collision Shapes and it does show the rays intersecting the area2d's, but still nothing is happening. Is there maybe something wrong with my raycasting or drawing code?

Comment: @AbsolutePickle42 As far as I can tell the code is fine (edit: I already pointed the possible problem in the answer). I think the problem could be elsewhere. For example: is the raycast enabled, are the collision mask and layers correct, are the nodes inside the correct parent in the scene tree…

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by that last comment? The one about the nodes in the correct parents in the scene tree. What would be the correct parent to put the raycast nodes in?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. It is possibly the dumbest mistake I have ever made. At the very top of the script, it says `extends Area2D`. HOWEVER, the actual node is a Node2D. I changed it to `extends Node2D`, and it works. But that does not mean your answers are not greatly appreciated as well as not useful. The lines are still not being drawn to the correct areas, but they are being drawn. I can use some of your earlier answers to help with that.

Comment: @AbsolutePickle42 I meant that you were checking the `get_parent`, and if that check fails it won't work. In fact, looking at it again, I have something to add to the answer. Edit: done. Edit 2: I would expect Godot to complain about the type of the script not matching. I remind you that you can use `breakpoint` or `print` to confirm is something is executing.